# Fire bug Events

Tags: events, firebug

How do a look for the events in firebug? I want to find out how many events that are their in the page using fire bug.

Comment: There is if you `console.log(...)` in the callback...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to look for all events on web page you may use EventBug plugin for firebug http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_Extensions#Eventbug

But if you want debug it you may use Event Listener Breakpoints in Google Chrome http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/chrome/devtools/docs/scripts-breakpoints.html#listeners